# gulp sass fail in simple gulp-sass test

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

https://github.com/somersbmatthews/gulp_test

I run gulp sass and no new css file is created. I get no errors.[image: terminal example]

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
   return gulp.src('gulp_test/scss/style.scss')
     .pipe(sass())
     .pipe(gulp.dest('gulp_test/css'))
});
```

My github repository is above with this simple gulp test.

This is my first time compiling scss into css.
Your help is appreciated. :)

Comment: paths is not `gulp_test/gulp_test/.....` ?

Comment: thanks @anderssonola I changed the paths to `./scss/style.scss` and `./css` and it worked: relative paths and absolute paths still confuse me.